Alternativas a Cloud Data que permita realizar un JOIN entre tablas de diferentes instancias de bases de datos e insertar el resultado en BigQuery
Estamos realizando  pruebas para hacer un Join (Unión) entre tablas de diferentes instancias de base de datos y escribir el resultado en un conjunto de datos de Big query, para ello utilizamos Cloud Data Fusion de Google cloud,  pero observamos que los costos del mismo son  muy elevados, pregunto si existe alguna herramienta o rutina que permita desarrollar esta integración de datos diferente a Cloud Data sin generar tantos costos

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

estás buscando una alternativa dentro del mismo google cloud platform?
